# How to write nearley grammar without loop?

Tags: parsing, grammar, nearley

I'm trying to use nearley.js to write a parse for ini-like files, with difference that string value may contain special control symbols. For example ^y mean the text after this symbol must be yellow, ^b - blue, &i - italic.

I use nearley playground (http://omrelli.ug/nearley-playground/) and started with very basic grammar for value:

```js
VALUE -> FONT_MODIFIER | COLOR_MODIFIER | TEXT

TEXT -> [^\n\^\&]:+

FONT_MODIFIER -> "&" [iIbBsS]

COLOR_MODIFIER -> "^" [aAbBcCdDfFgGiIkKmMoOpPrRsSwWyYnN]
```

But after I add test with random text (just letters, like "asdassad") after few seconds it gives me error `Possible infinite loop detected! Check your grammar for infinite recursion.`

What am I doing wrong? I just can't see where the loop comes from.

Comment: Worked fine when I tried it.

Comment: Here is what I did. Copy and paste the grammar into playground. Add a new test, and write random letters. Click a mouse somewhere outside the test editor field (bellow the test field for example), wait for a couple of seconds. Bellow the grammar edditor appears text "Possible infinite loop detected! Check your grammar for infinite recursion."

Comment: That's exactly what I did. I tried it again, on a different machine, and it still works perfectly. The only way I found to get that error message is to add, for example, `| VALUE` to the end of the first production. Maybe you should try clearing your browser cookies for that page, in case it's some weird browser bug.

Comment: Yeah, I tried clearing cache and cookies, tried different browser, different machine and still have the error message... Thank you for trying, though.

Comment: You got me. I guess you should just install it locally and run it with node.